# Plotting a histogram gives height error msg

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a histogram based on percentages, I keep getting the below error:

```
ValueError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 6 or scalar
```

It's something to do with this line but I'm not sure what's wrong with the height argument.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

xaxis=['epic1', 'epic2', 'epic3', 'epic4', 'epic5', 'epic6']
n=len(xaxis)
names = ('epic1', 'epic2', 'epic3', 'epic4', 'epic5', 'epic6')
data = {'done': [57,53,49,65,78,56,89], 
        'progress': [23,12,34,11,34,12,12], 
        'todo' :[11,5,6,7,8,4,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['total'] = df['done'] + df['progress'] + df['todo']

df['done_per'] = df['done'] / df['total'] * 100
df['progress_per'] = df['progress'] / df['total'] * 100
df['todo_per'] = df['todo'] / df['total'] * 100

barWidth = 0.25
# Create green Bars
plt.bar(xaxis, done_per, color='#b5ffb9', edgecolor='green', width=barWidth)
# Create orange Bars
plt.bar(xaxis, progress_per, bottom=done_per, color='#f9bc86',
        edgecolor='orange', width=barWidth)
# Create blue Bars
plt.bar(xaxis, todo_per, bottom=[i+j for i,j in zip(done_per, progress_per)],
        color='blue', edgecolor='blue', width=barWidth)

plt.xticks(xaxis, names)
plt.xlabel("epics")
plt.show()
```

Comment: guessing you want df['done_per'] not done_per, or to set done_per = to that first

Comment: You have a shape mismatch between the data columns and the `xaxis`, which isn't an issue except when you try to plot `xaxis` against the content of a column, i.e. `df['done_per']`. `d['done_per']` has 7 elements but `xaxis` has only 6. Different shapes for `x` and `height` are inherently incompatible for a `matplotlib.pyplot.bar` plot. What is it **exactly** you want to plot?

Comment: yup, I was wrong. Adding epic0 fixed it

Comment: thanks William and Jeremy! however now I'm getting a different error:

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is 7 items in `X_per`(yaxis) and 6 items in `xaxis`.

If you want 7 items instead. 
Adding `'epic7'` into `xaxis` should do the job. `xaxis.append('epic7')`

I think you had missed few lines in your code:

```
done_per = df['done_per']
progress_per = df['progress_per']
todo_per = df['todo_per']
```

Comment: I also thought those lines were missing, but adding an 'epic0' fixed it without those lines being added.

Comment: Its still not generating the barplot for me but now I'm seeing a different issue. I can close  this and raise another one